# how to change facebook api version in ios sdk

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

I need to change the api version of Facebook to some earlier version than 2.0. Facebook states that in the newest SDK (which I run), this can be done. But I can't find out how.

Comment: You can get older v3.x versions of the iOS SDK from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads) but doesn't look like pre v3 SDKs are available, unless you can find them on [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.

In the newest SDK, Facebook has a method called `- (void) overrideVersionPartWith:(NSString *)version;` in `FBRequest.h` which you can call and specify the version for a single action.